# Displaying image from folder/file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Dim ImagePath As String = "images/spaceship2.png"
Dim img1 As Bitmap
Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("images/spaceship2.png")

img1 = New Bitmap(ImagePath)
pb2.ImageLocation = ImagePath

pb1.Image = newImage
```

I want to display image from folder,  for example, student with an id number of 22137471, the picture with the name of  22137471 will be display on my picture box, between, i saw this code somewhere in google.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> i want to display image from folder, for example, student with an id
> number of 22137471, the picture with the name of 22137471 will be
> display on my picture box

Try something like...

```
Dim id As String = "22137471"
Dim folder As String = "c:\some path\folder"
Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, id & ".png")
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
```

Here's an updated version that doesn't lock the original image file:

```
Dim id As String = "22137471"
Dim folder As String = "c:\some path\folder"
Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, id & ".png")
Try
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Open)
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(fs))
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim msg As String = "Filename: " & filename &
        Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
        "Exception: " & ex.ToString
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error Opening Image File")
End Try
```

Comment: Dim id As String = LinkLabel1.Text
        Dim folder As String = "d:\image\"
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, id & ".jpg")
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename) 'it is not working, i will load it from datadisk d, my folder is image, inside it is the picture that will be display

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\some path\folder\myImage.jpg")
```